# tinyMCE 6 insert link to server side content

Tags: javascript, ajax, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm upgrading an old internal system used in my academic department. The page that I'm rewriting allows users to modify webpages containing information and content relevant to a course. The old system is using cleditor which I am replacing with the free version of tinyMCE 6.2.0.

One of the functionalities that needs to be replaced is a custom button that brings up a list of URLs to uploaded content and then turns the highlighted text into a link to the selected content ([example of this in current system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71I3D.png)). I have been able to create my own custom button, and I have found the `panel` and `selectbox` features, but I haven't found how to populate the list in `selectbox` using a URL like one can for `link_list`.

Below is an example of the javascript that I have:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '.course_page_editor',
    toolbar: 'custContentLink',
    setup: (editor) => {
        editor.ui.registry.addButton('custContentLink', {
            text: 'Insert Content Link',
            onAction: (_) => insert_content_link_dialog(tinymce.activeEditor)
    });
    }
});

function insert_content_link_dialog(editor)
{
    editor.windowManager.open({
        title: 'Insert Content Link',
        body: {
            type: 'panel',
            items: [{
                type: 'selectbox',
                name: 'content_list',
                label: 'Choose the file that the link should point to:',
                size: 5,
                //TODO: generate list of uploaded content URLs
                items: [
                    {text: 'Primary', value: 'primary style'},
                    {text: 'Success', value: 'success style'},
                    {text: 'Error', value: 'error style'}
                ],
                flex: true
            }]
        },
        onSubmit: function () {
            //TODO: replace highlighted text with selected link
        },
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Close',
                type: 'cancel',
                onclick: 'close'
            },
            {
                text: 'Add content link',
                type: 'submit',
                primary: true,
                enabled: true
            }
        ]
    });
};
```

How do I create a popup list of links to server side content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original process was overly complicated. TinyMCE has the [link_list](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/link/#link_list) functionality which does exactly what I'm looking for. I then created a page to return a JSON array of link items as outlined in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74604526/using-ajax-call-to-generate-array-for-link-list-for-tinymce) I asked.