# Using ajax call to generate array for link_list for tinymce

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask, tinymce

I'm trying to create a `link_list` in TinyMCE (version 6) using an AJAX call (not sure if this is the right way, but I'm trying to update old code). The backend is handled with Flask, which gets a tuple of dictionaries from the database where the `title` and `value` of each link are key-value pairs. I *believe* what I need to do is find a way to make the ajax call return the correct type of array, e.g.

```
my_ary=[
    { title: 'title 1',value: 'link1'},
    { title: 'title 2',value: 'link2'},
    { title: 'title 3',value: 'link3'},
]
```

Is this possible? Or am I heading in a completely incorrect direction? This is what I currently have-

tinyMCE intialization:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '.my_editor',
    plugins: ['link'],
    toolbar: 'link',
    link_list: (success) => {
        const links = update_item_list();
        success(links);
    },
});
```

javascript containing ajax call:

```
function update_item_list()
{
    my_link_list = $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_endpoint",
        data: {},
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(list)
        {
        const my_ary=Array.from(Array(list.length), () => ({ title: '', value: '' }))
        for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            {
            my_ary[i].title=list[i].title;
            my_ary[i].value=list[i].value;
            }
        },
        error: function(html, status)
        {
            alert("error: " + status);
        }
    });
    return my_link_list;
}
```

flask endpoint:

```
@my_project.route('/ajax_endpoint',methods=['POST'])
def ajax_endpoint():
    uploaded_items = ["{" + ", ".join([f"""'{key}': '{item.get(key)}'""" for key in item.keys()]) + "}" for item in get_link_items()]
    html = "[" + ", ".join(uploaded_items) + "]"

    return jsonify(html)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution without using ajax. Per [tinyMCE's documentation for link_list](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/link/#link_list), one can use a URL which returns JSON data. To accomplish this, I created a list of dictionaries with keys of "title" and "value" for each link, and then used `jsonify` when returning the list. Now, this is what my code looks like-

tinyMCE intialization:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '.my_editor',
    plugins: ['link'],
    toolbar: 'link',
    link_list: "ajax_endpoint"
    },
});
```

flask endpoint:

```
@my_project.route('/ajax_endpoint',methods=['POST'])
def ajax_endpoint():
    html = [{"title": item.get('title'), "value": item.get('value')} for item in get_link_items()]
    return jsonify(html)
```